# How to use DB transaction in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm using OctoberCMS and my rules is situated on model class. When occurs rules validation error, they throw new `ModelException`

trying:

```
DB::beginTransaction();
try 
{
  $model = new Model;
  $model->name = $name;
  $model->save();
 
  $another = new Another;
  $another->id = $model->id;
  $another->value = $value;
  $another->save();
  // all right
  DB::commit();
}
catch( ModelException $e ) 
{
  // some rules exception with one of these models
  DB::rollback();
}
```

Above code save the `$model` and if one `ModelException` is throw on saving `$another`, the `$model` record remains on database.

> mysql: 5.6.21
>
> tables: InnoDB

My workaround to make it work is:

```
    $model = new Model;
    $model->name = $name;
    $model->save();
    try 
    {
      $another = new Another;
      $another->id = $model->id;
      $another->value = $value;
      $another->save();
    }
    catch( ModelException $e ) 
    {
      $model->delete();
      $myerrors = $another->errors()->all();
    }
```

How make Laravel transactions work in described situation?

Comment: You can do something like `$model->another()->associate($another)->save()` depending on the relationship. Doing this you can also drop `$model->save()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try this:

```
DB::transaction(function()
{
    // Write your code here...
});
```

> Note: Any exception thrown within the transaction closure will cause
>   the transaction to be rolled back automatically. [Laravel Website](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/database#database-transactions)

Also you may [read this](http://fideloper.com/laravel-database-transactions), very nicely explained.

Comment: dude, i did read this article and all others on internet. this not worked for me using OctoberCMS and racked my brain. i give up transaction for now.  but thanks :-)